# GruntJS copy plugin only files into directory

Tags: file, copy, gruntjs

Is it possible with the grunt-contrib-copy plugin or any other copy plugin to copy only files?

I am currently using the following task:

```
copy: {
        vendorJs: {
                files: [
                    {
                        dest: "app/dist/client/vendor/js/",
                        src: ["bower_components/**/*.min.js"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

So how can i copy only files in my destination without taking the folder structure of the src object in consideration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found out that the grunt file pattern serves a "flatten" attribute which can be used to achieve the task above.

Following configuration solved my problem:

```
copy: {
        vendorJs: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        flatten: true,
                        filter: "isFile",
                        cwd: "bower_components/",
                        dest: "app/dist/client/vendor/js/",
                        src: ["**/*.min.js"]
                    }
                ]
            }
```